Gz doom giving fatal error
I downloaded GZDoom and whenever I try to run it I get this fatal error:

How do I fix it?
After adding doom2.wad to the config directory it booted but now there's this strange green bar  covering my screen, and I'm getting under 10 fps which is strange for a game from the 90s. This computer is from 2008 so i don't understand what could be the cause of these errors

please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, explain whether you followed the error suggestions, what was the result  and which Linux distro/version you are using.

Your original question has been answered - how to fix the fatal error.  You should not keep piling on with editing more questions into the same post. You should accept the answer that told you how to fix the fatal error and then ask a new question.

@OrganicMarble It looks like an OK question now that an answer has been given and that answer has been  accepted. Perhaps upvoting the question would be in order to deter potential downvoters from going on a trip.

@karel done, thanks

gzdoom is a game engine and does not include the game data required to actually play a game.
You must place the game data in the directory specified in the error message (or symlink to it, which is what I do). Alternately, also as mentioned in the error message, you can edit the config file to point to a different directory containing game data.
If you don't own a copy of the game(s) supported by gzdoom, you can download completely free game data that works with gzdoom, for example freedoom

I can't find the correct config file because searching for config in the file thing comes up with hundreds of files named config, any way to find the correct file? I have a .WAD but I can't find the file to put it in

@Araylln by default it's the location shown on the error message, although it uses a maybe confusing shortcut. By default you should put the .WAD file in the directory /home/your-user-name/.config/gzdoom/ Replace your-user-name with your user name, and don't miss the "." before "config"  Also possibly confusing, files that start with a "." are hidden from file managers by default.  There's an option to show them in the file manager somewhere, in the one I use (caja) it's pressing cntrl-h So ".config" probably does not show up in your file manager.

Now it runs but it has more bugs :/

You should accept this answer since it explained how to fix the fatal error and then ask a new question about the new problem.
